# Glassfish HTTP and HTTPS combine

Tags: http, ssl, https, glassfish

i have a web application (e-trade). Normal pages uses http protokol. I must do some https activated pages. My question is, how i can arrange the Glassfish server, this pages use http , those pages use https, How can i implements this idea on Glassfish server or with alternative configurations.

Comment: No one know? How can i implement switching http to https and https to http back!!

Answer (score 0):

GlassFish supports both protocols on different listeners. So the place you have to look for is the server configuration. This is a good place to start with it: http://javadude.wordpress.com/2010/04/06/getting-started-with-glassfish-v3-and-ssl/
"Switching" between both actually means redirecting. And that is exactly what the name says. You have to redirect to the secure pages and back. There isn't any "application-magic" which does the trick. Hope that helps.

Comment: we have solved the question by using two listener class, when condition happend, it changes the http to https and port numbers vice versa